# How would you create a .csv file with Data log name followed by a time stamp? Python 2.7.3

Tags: parsing, csv, timestamp

Python 2.7.3

Hi, I am writing a code to retrieve an input from the user to name a file. After obtaining the name of the file, I want to convert it to a .csv file with the name followed by a time stamp of the current date.

Example:

```
Prompt User: Create a title for a .csv file: 
User Entry: Logs
Desired Output: Logs07302014-1:27PM.csv
```

Code:

```
import time

title = raw_input("Create a title for a .csv file: ")

current_time = time.strftime("%m.%d.%y-%H%MPM.csv", time.localtime())
outFile = title + '%s' %current_time

f = csv.writer(open(outFile, 'ab'),delimiter=",", quotechar=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Error Message:

```
File "titlecsv.py"
f = csv.writer(open([outFile], 'ab'), delimiter=",", quotechar=" ",quoting=cv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

I know that the output file can only take one string. I'm not sure how to make my desired output file to be one string from the current code.

When I print the outfile for debugging, it displays a list:

```
['title','timestamp']
```

But it's supposed to just be one string, rather than a split string. How would I solve this?

Update: this works when I use f = open instead of f = csv.writer, but I would like to in case I have to add data onto the excel file in the future. Is there another command like f.writerow without using csv.writer?

Comment: You have syntax error. outFile = title + '%s' %current_time

Comment: The comma or + sign still works for me. I'll change it to + though. Aside from that, I still have the same error message.

Comment: Update, this works when I use f = open instead of f = csv.writer, but I would like to in case I have to add data onto the excel file in the future. Is there another command like f.writerow without using csv.writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
import time

title = raw_input("Create a title for a .csv file: ")

current_time = time.strftime("%m.%d.%y-%H%MPM.csv", time.localtime())
logname = title + '%s' %current_time

outFile = ''.join(logname) #combines list to a string

f = csv.writer(open(outFile, 'ab'),delimiter=",", quotechar=" ", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) #Create the .csv file with the string as the name
```